# Wrapfig used in conflicting environment

Tags: wrapfigure, wrapfig

I have been searching and trying for a while looking for the cause of the warning and the unexpected placement of the figure at the bottom of the text when it should be beside the text. I thought of providing an MWE of the error. Problem is that there is no problem when the code is very short. I get what I expected. But I am writing a book with `twoside` option with uneven inner and outer margins set in `geometry` package. The content is already too long to actually pinpoint the cause. I made a separate chapter for making some biography and add the author's picture at the side of the text, preferably on the left top corner (at the start of the text). In this chapter there are no lists or code listings or whatsoever that may conflict with `wrapfigure` environment. But still I get the warning and wrong placement of figure. I am using Overleaf for the project. And the chapter is just a separate file that is included in the main script via `input` command. Writing small code with `wrapfig` is just fine. I might try using `minipage` as an alternative. But I thought this could be the best. Any clarification and solution would be helpful.

[image: From Overleaf]

My preamble is as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{book}

%\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig, blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref} % For making multiple references.
\usepackage[numbered, useliterate]{mcode} % For MATLAB codes.
%\usepackage{xcolor} % For colored environments or texts.
\usepackage{listings} % For code listings.
\usepackage{caption, subcaption} % For figures and subfigures.
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm,enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\graphicspath{ {./graphics/} }
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{example}
%\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in, outer=0.5in, inner=0.75in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=2, title=Alphabetical Index, options=-s]
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{verbatim} % For commenting block of codes
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{emptypage} % For inserting empty pages at the end of chapters.
\usepackage{lineno}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of Figures}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{List of Table}
\allowdisplaybreaks
% For reducing space between chapter title and top of page
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display] 
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge} 
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{40pt}
%

% For header and footer line on every page
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\lfoot{cdass text(import)}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\makeatletter
\def\chaptermark#1{%
          \markboth{\MakeUppercase{%
            \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne \if@mainmatter
              \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ \fi\fi#1}}{}}
\makeatother
%

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
```

Comment: the preamble is not that helpful to debug your problem, almost all of it will not be related so it just complicates debugging. What is needed is a small self contained example that reproduces the problem. Once you make that you can easily test deleting packages in the preamble and only post the document using packages needed to show the problem.

Comment: in particular the error messag esays that wrapfig is in a conflicting environment (which usually means it is in a list or display environment) but your image shows it at the same level as `\chapter` which is usually at the top level. In any case the error is about the position of wrapfig in the document so not really related to the preamble settings at all.

Comment: Exactly, I tried to find the cause by actually copying everything from the preamble and making a separate script with just one chapter and the `wrapfigure` environment. I found no problems and no warnings. Everything went perfect.

Comment: I tried in `backmatter` as well. Getting the same warning and wrong placement. Doesn't matter if I put before or after `printindex`.

Comment: Start from a copy of your document, move the wrapfig as early as possible while it shows the error, then delete everything after it, then delete everything in the preamble not used in the new small example. Then post the resulting small complete document that shows the error.  It sounds like your entire document is in an environment, possiby an unclosed abstract.

Comment: Hmm, good idea. Nice way to probe. Will take some time.

Comment: Okay so I found the cause by bringing the `wrapfigure`  at the very early of the book. Turns out someone forgot or didn't know to enclose text size commands and align commands such as `large` or `justify` using curly braces. So `{\large <text>} \begin{wrapfigure}<content>\end{wrapfigure}` gives no warning and misplacement while `\large <text> \begin{wrapfigure}<content>\end{wrapfigure}` does.

Comment: large is fine but `justify` should never be used as a command it is like `\center`  and is the internal implementation of the `begin{justify}` environment. ragged2e adds that for completeness to match flushleft and flushright but I have never seen any document where it is useful:  justification is the default in tex. If you have any instances of `\justify` simply remove them.

Comment: Is there a complete resource or useful source of information that tells what kind of environments may conflict with `wrapfig` environments? Or is it almost all environments that conflict with them?

Comment: wrapfig sty has some comments but basically anything affecting the paragraph shape so mostly lists including trivlists such as quote, center, justify  ...

Comment: but the error from wrapfig is just a symptom the document was already in error if it's all in the scope of \justify

Comment: Had I not used `wrapfig` I wouldn't know `justify` was hiding somewhere since no warning was there to tell it. The text contents in the document appeared just fine to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example (as clarified in comments) can be simplified to

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\center

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.5\textwidth}
  
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

which produces the warning

```
Package wrapfig Warning: wrapfigure used inside a conflicting environment on in
put line 9.
```

The error here is `\center` which is the internal form of `\begin{center}` and should not be used as a command. The command form is `\centering` which makes no warning.

The actual case was `\justify` from `ragged2e` which is again the internal environment form, the command form is `\justifying`. However for this case the fix is simpler: you can just remove the command. The  `ragged2e` package adds `\justifying` as a complement to `\centering`, `\raggedright` and `\raggedleft`, but justification is the default in TeX and I have never seen any valid use of this command. When it is used it is usually an attempt to mitigate a earlier error where `\raggedright` has not been used with the correct scope so is applying to too much of the document, but it is much better to fix the use of `\raggedright` so that it is in a group and ends at the correct place rather than try to undo the raggedness by applying `\justifying`
within the ragged section.